# Grant read to Elasticache on S3 object with boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-elasticache

I have a script that uploads a file to S3 then starts an Elasticache server seeded with the file. [Elasticache documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/backups-seeding-redis.html#backups-seeding-redis-grant-access) says to provide read and read permission permissions to `540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353` which represents the canonical ID for any region that's not GovCloud or China.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
s3_cl = boto3.client('s3')
s3_cl.put_object_acl(Bucket='bucket-name', Key='file.rdb', GrantRead='540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353')
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObjectAcl operation: Argument format not recognized
```

What parameter am I supposed to provide to `GrantRead`? My understanding was that it's a grantee, which can be a canonical ID, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try GrantRead='id=540804...'

Comment: @jarmod That was it! Nowhere in [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectacl) do they mention you have to format the parameter that way, that I  could find. That's pretty infuriating. If you make it an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should provide grantees in one of the following formats:

- id=<canonical user ID of the grantee>
- email=<email address of the grantee>
- uri=<URI of the grantee group>
- displayname=<screen name of the grantee>
- type=<type of grantee>

I inferred this information from the awscli [put-object-acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html) documentation.